# Search excluding file name on GitHub?

Tags: github

Situation: You are trying to find the usages of a feature of some common framework, and want to only find client code instead of 1000 copies of the library itself. Further compounding the problem is that you can't exclude forks to get rid of these copies since the framework source is not officially on GitHub, so all the copies are not recorded as forks.

You know that all the copies of the framework source have their references in `MtpConstants.java`, so all you need to do is exclude that file from your searches and you'll get rid of the framework copies.

I've tried:

`FORMAT_MS_POWERPOINT_PRESENTATION`, set language to Java: 3500 results.

`FORMAT_MS_POWERPOINT_PRESENTATION NOT filename:MtpConstants.java`: 0 results even though there should be some

`FORMAT_MS_POWERPOINT_PRESENTATION AND NOT filename:MtpConstants.java`: same

`FORMAT_MS_POWERPOINT_PRESENTATION AND (NOT filename:MtpConstants.java)`: finds only results in `MtpConstants.java`, the opposite of the intended effect.

Is there a working way to exclude file names in GitHub search?

Answer (score 3):

According to GitHub support, this is accomplished by using the `-` sign:

`FORMAT_MS_POWERPOINT_PRESENTATION -filename:MtpConstants.java`

and I can confirm that this indeed works.

### Documentation

Search by filename: https://help.github.com/en/articles/searching-code#search-by-filename

Excluding results: https://help.github.com/en/articles/understanding-the-search-syntax#exclude-certain-results

Comment: Please edit your answer including a link to the referring GitHub support answer/page as well.

Comment: @marikamitsos done